# Can i use eloquent ORM and Query Builder in one place (one model)?

Tags: laravel-5

I want using Eloquent ORM and Query Builder in one place (one model), Thanks

```html
<?php

namespace App\Inventory_material;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class InventoryMaterialModel extends Model
{
    // Eloquent ORM
    protected $table = 'table_name';

    // Query Builder
     public function getter($field, $value) {
      $query = DB::table('inventory_material')->where('id', $value)->value($field);
      return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `getter` method if you're using Eloquent, it is all taken care of under the hood.

```
class InventoryMaterialModel extends Model
{
    // Eloquent ORM
    protected $table = 'table_name';
}

class InventoryController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        return App\Inventory_material\InventoryMaterialModel::findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```